# Insert to postgres DB: invalid String format (parsing exception error)

Tags: postgresql, exception

I am creating a log db where I track execution steps and catch where it might or might not fail.
I am having issues inserting the Exceptions thrown to a DB.

I am calling an endpoint first in order then query a django database.
In this case I wanted to catch a mistake in the selection_query and thus being unable to fetch the data from the DB.
I want to log this message.

Example:

**Exception catch**

```
try:
    select_query = "SELECT columnn from row"
    cur.execute(select_query)
    selected_vals = cur.fetchall()
except Exception as e:
    response = insert_into_logging(message =  f"{e}", logging_id = 3)
```

**Error**

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

This is because of the value passed in the message argument.
(`message =  f"{e}"`)
It is not insertable in the DB

The value of "e" is:

```
auto_close_alarm relation "row" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT columnn from row
                            ^
```

I tried to pass

- `str(e)`

Value passed: identical output as above

- `repr(e.args[0])`

Output: `'relation "row" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT columnn from row\n                            ^\n'`

- `repr(e)`

Value passed: `UndefinedTable('relation "row" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT columnn from row\n                            ^\n',)`

And multiple other ways but to no avail.
They all result in the same `JSONDecodeError`.

Basically the key problem is that this is not a valid String format for it to be able to be parsed in the DB.
All I need is a representation of this `Exception` error for it to be insertable

Flow of data:

**insert function**

```
def insert_into_logging(message, logging_id, date_time):
    url = f"""url/insert-into-logging/"""

    data = {
        "message": message,
        "logging_id": logging_id,
    }
    response = r.post(url, data=json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
    print(response)
    return response.json()
```

**Querying DB**

```
def insert_to_logging(request):
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    if request.method != 'POST':
        print(request.method)
        return JsonResponse({'status':'error', 'message':'Client insertion only accepts post requests.' + str(request.method)})

    today = datetime.today()

    body = json.loads(request.body)
    message = body.get('message')
    logging_id = body.get('logging_id')    
    Logging.objects.create(message = message, logging_id = logging_id, time_stamp = today)
    return JsonResponse({'status':'OK', 'message':'Logging successful'})
```

**Django Model**

```
class Logging(models.Model):
    objects = GetOrNoneManager()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    logging_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'logging'
```

Comment: Well, perhaps there is no table called `row`?

Comment: Yes I do know that but that is not the issue. I want to be able to catch this error in the Logging DB

Comment: Its not about being able to query that specific DB table, its about catching this mistake in another DB

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: Programming language is python